# Simple custom Exception do not raise the same way as bultins

Tags: python, exception, python-3.8

I have a multiprocessed program - 4 processes, and inside these i spawn multiple threads so it is multithreaded as well. I do not have so much experience with tracing and debugging these, i am getting into it now. I have this code block in my tcp server though:

I have Exceptions like this

```
class Error(Exception):
  """Basic exception"""
class NoDataReceived(Error):
  """Raised when there is no data"""
```

Now the code

```
try:
  ...
  if True:
    raise ValueError('No data receieved')      # <--- this will print
    # raise NoDataReceived('There is no data') # <--- when i use this it won't print

except ValueError as err:       # bultin
  print('err')
except NoDataReceived as err:   # custom
  print('err')   # Does NOT print..?
```

Now the thing is, when i raise ValueError, it prints out, when i raise the custom NoDataRecieved, it does not print at all.

I need to say it is multithreaded program and multiprocessed as well (threads within process), if i run this piece of code in singlethreaded simple script, it works as it should. I do not like this behaviour. Before i build anything on it i need to understand this better. I know i could use sys_traceback, but i really want to make this work as it should, simply.

Do you have an explanation for me my friends?

[Python 3.8]

Thank you for your time, Q.

Comment: You should have posted the whole traceback (or at least inspect it). Is it *NoDataRec**ie**ved* or *NoDataRec**ei**ved*? Cause you define one and catch the other. Also as a side note, threads in *Python* don't actually run in parallel. *Google* would yield lots of results on this topic: ***Python GIL***.

Comment: Yeah i know about GIL, thats why i use multiprocessing, to actually run it in parallel, and NoDataRecieved was just a typo here, not in my actual code, i edited it, but still the problem persits